# Is there any situation in which you would use an Object table and an ObjectInstance table in a relational database

Tags: orm, relational-database

Is there any situation in which you would create a table called Node and another table called NodeInstance if you were designing the DB schema to serve as the persistence and CRUD layer for an entity called Node using a relational database?

This question has been posted to try to dissuade my colleagues from making costly mistakes during the design of the database schema whose purpose is to serve as the storage, persistence and CRUD data-layer for the backend of an iPad app I am working on and also to avoid creating  bugs and issues which will be a maintenance nightmare in the future. Because I am under NDA, I cannot post any details regarding the exact nature of the project, except to say that the main  entity that we are creating the CRUD layer on the server for, is called a Node. Therefore, I have recommended to my colleagues who are working on the backend to create a class called Node to represent the Node object and to insert rows in the Node table in the relational DB for the  Create operation, with a new row representing every instance of the Node which is created using the client app, in true ORM fashion.

However, for some reason, my colleagues seem to think that having 1 table for persisting the Node objects is the wrong approach and the right approach is to create a Node table and a NodeInstance table and that maintaining 2 tables in parallel to manage the persistence of the Node entity is more efficient / performant. Since I am a bit of an ORM nerd and also a DB-schema geek, I have been trying to figure out if there is any planet in the known universe where using a 2 table approach to persist and perform CRUD on 1 entity, would be a good idea but in all scenarios, it seems that this adds code complexity, not to mention that it necessitates unnecessary SQL joins, multiple queries to maintain data-integrity, issues with atomic transactions, and concurrency issues. However, if there is anyone on stackoverflow that can help me understand why my colleagues approach is sane, then I would like to have an open mind and try to entertain the notion that my colleagues are right. However, at the time of writing this, I am convinced that my colleagues do not have a complete understanding of ORM and are therefore, thinking of using 2 tables for persisting 1 entity. Please do shine some wisdom on this matter, my respected stackoverflow peers and experts.

Comment: Paragraphs, please. And draw out the real question/problem. I would read it if it was suitable formatted. But it isn't.

Comment: Sorry. Formatted it better now. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: I do not understand what your colleagues recommend. What would be stored in the Node and what in the NodeInstance?

Comment: I am not completely sure either. I am as lost as you are about what fields they intend to store in each table. I'm afraid to ask.

Comment: Perhaps ask them how a "Node" *differs from* and *relates to* a "NodeInstance"; maybe one contains versioning information or otherwise information that does not always exist? That is, clarify what *"instance"* means. At this stage, *do not* focus about performance/joins, but rather how to model the data with the best normalization and expression of the problem at hand.

Comment: I've voted as "not constructive" because there is not enough information to go anywhere. In any case, I view the *RA model as most important* with the client ORM being a convenient way to access it in common cases. If the ORM isn't as accommodating as it needs to be, kick it out the way (or get a different one). There will always be an "impedance mismatch". Choose good battles.